# Can I make popup screen or file upload automatically with selenium?

Tags: selenium

Good morning. I have a web page control with selenium. However, when I click the button of the site, a pop-up screen appears and I want to test that the file attachment is saved by pressing the file attachment button in it. Can you control selenium with two windows (parent, child-popup) going up and down?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to interact with file upload dialog which is native window via selenium. That is not possible. However you can select file to upload using sendKeys without the dialog being opened.

Something like that

```
fileInput.sendKeys("/path/to/local/file");
```